php listener for stream content transfer
I want to find out if I have any endpoints in my API that have more than a minute between sending data chunks via a stream. (e.g. because of long running sql queries)
I would therefore like to log whenever new data is sent to the stream.
I use laravel, but I think the solution is rather related to php streams.
return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::stream(function () {
       $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

            SomeTable::query()
                           ->where(...)
                           ->chunk(1000)
                           ->forEach($row => fputcsv($output, $row->toArray());
  

            fclose($output);
        }, 200, [
            "Content-type" => "text/csv",
            "Content-Disposition" => 'attachment; filename=stream.csv"',
            "Pragma" => "no-cache",
            "Cache-Control" => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
            "Expires" => "0"
        ]);
    }

This code retrieves data in chunks of 1000 from the db and then sends these 1000 via the stream. I would like to find places in my codebase where such queries take more than 1 minute so I can optimize them.
I am not interested in any queries that take long, but only those that are used within the context of a stream.
I am therefore looking for a solution that hooks into the stream and allows me to run some code whenever data is transferred.
I am aware that I could just add the code to that specific part of my codebase, but I am looking for a solution that listens to all streams without having to add code everywhere.

I managed to do it via ob_start($callback)
this allows me to run code whenever the buffer is flushed (= data sent to the client)
